# Tengo un error en una consulta mysql usando php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy iniciando en PDO y necesito hacer una consulta, pero no la realiza, no sé si el problema sea con las variables que utilizo en el query o estoy declarando algo mal en mi código.

Este código es el de mis variables:

```
foreach ($_POST['ciudades'] as $value) {
  if ($current != $num_countries-1){
     $where2 = $where2 . $where . "'" . $value . "'" . ' ' . 'AND' . ' ' . 'anio = ' . $anio . ' ' . 'AND' . ' ' . 'clas = ' . "'" . $subclas . "'" . ')' . ' ' . 'OR' . ' '. $where . "'" . $value . "'" . ' ' . 'AND' . ' ' . 'anio = ' . $anio . ' ' . 'AND' . ' ' . 'clas = ' . "'unica'" . ')' . ' ' . 'OR' . ' ';
  }else{
     $where3 = $where . "'" . $value . "'" . ' ' . 'AND' . ' ' . 'anio = ' . $anio . ' ' . 'AND' . ' ' . 'clas = ' . "'" . $subclas . "'" . ')' . ' ' . 'OR' . ' '. $where . "'" . $value . "'" . ' ' . 'AND' . ' ' . 'anio = ' . $anio . ' ' . 'AND' . ' ' . 'clas = ' . "'unica'" . ')';
  }$current++;
}
```

Y el código de la consulta es el siguiente:

```
    $q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM :tipoTarifa2 WHERE :where2 :where3');
    $q ->execute(array("tipoTarifa2"=>$tipoTarifa2,"where2"=>$where2,"where3"=>$where3));
    $result = $q->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $data) {
      echo $data["Id"];
    }
```

Comment: **Los nombres de las tablas ni las columnas no pueden ser enviados por parámetros en PDO**

Comment: @Dev.Joel entonces de qué manera puedo pasar las variables?

Comment: **Concatenación simple !** , `"SELECT * FROM $tipoTarifa2 "`

Comment: si imprimes la consulta como tal q arroja?

Comment: Por experiencia, cuando implementas tu propia clase para PDO es una maravilla. Ejemplo:   `$array=array(...); $sql="SELECT..."; $datos=$mipdo->query($sql,$array);` y ya tienes tu resultado en `$datos`. Esta es la clase que uso: https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO . Verás varios ejemplos de consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que veo en el codigo, te falta en el array del execute() los dos puntos ":tipoTarifa2" para setear las variables, trata de imprimir los erores con $q->errorInfo();

slds

Comment: podrias agregar un ejemplo, tambien trata de no abreviar por si usuarios de otro idioma ven la respuesta